# GreenDao "PRIMARY KEY must be unique" error happen despite of added "myEntity.addIdProperty().autoIncreament()"

Tags: android, unique, primary-key, greendao

I am new with GreenDAO. This is my Generator class

```
public class FlashCardGenerator {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Schema schema = new Schema(1, "com.flashcard.model");

        Entity lesson = schema.addEntity("Lesson");
        lesson.addIdProperty().autoincrement();
        lesson.addStringProperty("LessonName");
        lesson.addStringProperty("ShortDes");
        lesson.addStringProperty("LongDes");

        Entity card = schema.addEntity("Card");
        card.addIdProperty().autoincrement();
        card.addStringProperty("SourceText");
        card.addStringProperty("TargetText");
        card.addByteArrayProperty("Image");

        Property lessonID = card.addLongProperty("lessonID").getProperty();
        card.addToOne(lesson, lessonID);
        ToMany lessonToCard = lesson.addToMany(card, lessonID);
        lessonToCard.setName("cards");

        new DaoGenerator().generateAll(schema,"../app/src/main/java");
    }
}
```

Although I add id column to "lesson" and make it auto increament. When I using this code

```
DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(this, "flashcard-db", null);
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
DaoMaster daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);DaoSession daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
LessonDao lessonDao = daoSession.getLessonDao();
Lesson lesson = new Lesson( 1L,"Demo L1", "Nothing", "nothing");
long l = lessonDao.insert(lesson);

if (l > 0) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail! OMG", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

The first time I run project, the record is inserted successfully, the second time I run the project, I got "PRIMARY KEY must be unique" error. This is a common error when the primary key is violented. But I set it too AutoIncreament? May be because I set the Id to `1L`? Generated-class is not recommended to modify, and all of Lesson's constructor is have "Id" param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, very quick, after some search on [GreenDao support](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/how-to-get-started/), I found the solution, just set the ID parameter to NULL, instead of any "long number". It's worked. I will keep the post here to anyone after me meet something like this

The code for inserting will be:

```
Lesson lesson = new Lesson( null ,"Demo L1", "Nothing", "nothing");
        long l = lessonDao.insert(lesson);
```